# Send keys with ctrl alt i

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application that is trying to send the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, but it doesn’t work. This code I set to a button. How can I do this without special permissions? I tried this web example :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("i”+ "{^} + {%}")
End Sub
```

But it doesn’t work and just makes my computer slow and types random strings.

Comment: If only there was a way for us to see the code you're using now to determine whether there's something wrong with it.

Comment: @zackraiyan : To "send keys" literally means sending keys (keystrokes) to an application. In other words, simulating keyboard input. The `SendKeys` class works by sending the keys you specify, i.e. `SendKeys.Send("Hello{ENTER}")` types the word "Hello" and creates a new line.

Comment: @zackrayian : As to why your code appeared to work: You must have overlooked something, because _**if**_ your code would _actually_ work the way you think it does, it would violate the laws of mathematics. Here's a simple example showing that it infact doesn't work, apart from the method I mentioned: https://ideone.com/e5vDKl